# Find different in two jsonb , PostgreSQL trigger function

Tags: database, postgresql, database-trigger

user

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    "status" integer NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  );
```

user_track

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user_track"(
    "date" timestamp without time zone,
    "by_user_id" integer, 
    "origin_value" jsonb,
    "new_value" jsonb
  );
```

function

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_track_insert()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_track(date, new_value)
       VALUES(NEW.create_date, row_to_json(NEW)::jsonb);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_track_delete()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_track(date, by_user_id, origin_value)
       VALUES(create_date, user_id, row_to_json(OLD)::jsonb);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_track_update()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  DECLARE
    js_new jsonb := row_to_json(NEW)::jsonb;
    js_old jsonb := row_to_json(OLD)::jsonb;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_track(date, by_user_id, origin_value, new_value)
       VALUES(NEW.create_date, OLD.id, js_old - js_new, js_new - js_old);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

trigger

```
  CREATE TRIGGER user_track_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON "user"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_track_insert();
  CREATE TRIGGER user_track_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON "user"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_track_delete();
  CREATE TRIGGER user_track_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON "user"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_track_update();
```

When I do update in pgadmin got error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb - jsonb
LINE 2:        VALUES(NEW.create_date, OLD.id, js_old - js_new, js_n...
                                                      ^
ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb - jsonb
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function user_track_update() line 6 at SQL statement
```

- I only want to save json data present changed column/value not whole row all column.
  I can't find jsonb - jsonb in document, so seems there is no such operator ...
- How to pass parameter into `user_track_delete` function, for example if I want to some other use.id who execute this action ?

PostgreSQL 9.5.2

Comment: It looks like you're trying to subtract two JSONB values, and that's why you're getting the no operator matches error message. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, though. Could you explain your intent further?

Comment: I want to only save json data with changed key(column) value not save all column(whole row).

Comment: Probably it will be useful reading: [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus).

Comment: @Abelisto I saw that before, but can't solve my problem :(

Comment: To get the 1-level JSON difference: `select json_object_agg(t2.k, t2.v) from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(old)) as t1(k,v) join jsonb_each(to_jsonb(new)) as t2(k,v) on (t1.k = t2.k) where t1.v <> t2.v;`

Comment: You need to install the `-` operator for `jsonb`: https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op  Alternatively you can use a `hstore`  column: http://okbob.blogspot.de/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html