# Postgresql Trigger log only changes of affected columns

Tags: postgresql

Following a helpfull article on [Tracking changes in PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) I got a well working trigger function that tracks changes of all the tables associated with that trigger-function.
The function stores the whole OLD an NEW row content as JSON, which is fine, but with a lot of columns it's hard to get an overview of the real changes.

I'm looking for a way to store only the content of the columns where the NEW and the OLD values have changed. Therefore I added a new column 'changes'.

Here the table that stores the history:

```
CREATE TABLE public.t_history
(
  id integer serial,
  tstamptz timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  schemaname text,
  tabname text,
  operation text,
  who text DEFAULT "current_user"(),
  changes  text,
  new_val json,
  old_val json,
  CONSTRAINT pk_t_history PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Since the trigger-function is quite generic I would like to use a way to compare the two json-colums new_val and old_val or have a way using a foreach loop to look at each column without specifying hard coded column names. The result, the real changes should then be stored in the column 'changes'.

This is how the trigger-function looks like:

```
REATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.change_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN
                IF      TG_OP = 'INSERT'
                THEN
                        INSERT INTO public.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val)
                                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW));
                        RETURN NEW;

                ELSIF   TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
                THEN
                        INSERT INTO public.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val)
                                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP,
                                        row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
                        RETURN NEW;
                ELSIF   TG_OP = 'DELETE'
                THEN
                        INSERT INTO public.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val)
                                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD));
                        RETURN OLD;
                END IF;
        END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

Comment: btw why aren't you using jsonb? jsonb does have equality operator

Comment: still running on Postgresql 9.2.4. I know I need to upgrade.

Comment: You do. Also of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296728/find-different-in-two-jsonb-postgresql-trigger-function

Comment: You could also use a stored procedure written in python, v8 or so

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you really need to upgrade. The possibilities in 9.2 regarding this are rather limited. The following answer therefore assumes a minimum of 9.4, the lowest currently still supported version.

---

You can generate a set of key value pairs using `json_each_text()` and then filter for different values having the same key.

Then you can build some JSON from there, for example one JSON object per column using `json_build_object()` and aggregate them in an JSON array using `json_agg()`. You didn't specify the exact format you want. So this is just an example. You may come up with a different idea there.

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('column',
                                  old2.key,
                                  'old',
                                  old2.value,
                                  'new',
                                  new2.value))
       FROM (VALUES (1,
                     2,
                     3)) old(i,
                             j,
                             k)
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1,
                                3,
                                4)) new(i,
                                        j,
                                        k)
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json(old)) old2
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json(new)) new2
       WHERE old2.key = new2.key
             AND old2.value <> new2.value;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=9de1c83808affa15909f50e79764f9db)

Note: That `VALUES` x `VALUES` cross join is only for the demonstration so that I have a `new` and an `old`, I'm not in a trigger after all. In the trigger of course you already have `new` and `old` and can skip that and use a `FROM` clause like:

```
FROM json_each_text(row_to_json(old)) old2
     CROSS JOIN json_each_text(row_to_json(new)) new2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticky bit's answer was really helpful, just in case someone wants to see how it's applied to a trigger here's an example:

1. First we can create a variable were we will store the changes.

```
    DECLARE
    changes   JSONB;
```

2. Then we insert into it the updated columns

```
      SELECT INTO changes JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('updatedColumn',
                                                       old2.key,
                                                       'oldValue',
                                                       old2.value,
                                                       'newValue',
                                                       new2.value))
        FROM JSON_EACH_TEXT(ROW_TO_JSON(old)) old2
                 CROSS JOIN JSON_EACH_TEXT(ROW_TO_JSON(new)) new2
        WHERE old2.key = new2.key
          AND old2.value <> new2.value;
```

3. After that we can insert this variable into our table

```
  INSERT INTO t_history(mycolumn)
    VALUES (changes);
```

This works even if the column has the "json" data type.